# Появление поля select при выборе в другом select

Tags: html, php

помогите с кодом! В этом коде появляется два поля "Регион" и "Город" оба select.

1.Как сделать так чтоб поле "Город" появлялось только тогда когда пользователь выбирает "Регион"?

2.И каждый раз когда поле "Регион" выбранно и загружается поле "Город" в нем список городов обновлялся, а не просто скрывалось и показывалось поле.

3.И как их сделать обязательными для заполнения (пока пользователь не заполнит нельзя было нажать на кнопку опубликовать)?

```
<div class="box location"> <h2><?php _e('Ваши данные', 'russia'); ?></h2> <div class="row"> <label for="countryId"><?php _e('Country', 'russia'); ?></label> <?php ItemForm::country_select(osc_get_countries(), osc_user()) ; ?> </div> <div class="row"> <label for="regionId"><?php _e('Region', 'russia'); ?></label>

<?php ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions(), osc_user()) ; ?> </div>
<div class="row">
<label for="city"><?php _e('City', 'russia'); ?></label>
<?php ItemForm::city_select(osc_get_cities(), osc_user()) ; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Игра - угадай мой фреймворк.

Comment: Угадываю: **[osclass][1]**


  [1]: http://doc.osclass.org/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

1. Не надо использовать конструкторы форм - лучше чистый html+Js (jQuery). Настоятельно рекомендую посмотреть и изучить jQuery - то что вы хотите сделать - на нем делается очень быстро.

Код писать не буду -напишу принцип

- На событие выбора select (Регион) вешаем обработчик, в нем:
- если выбрано пустое значение - то удаляем все значения в select (Город) и  скрываем его.
- если значение не пустое - то удаляем все значения в select (Город),отправляем Ajax запрос на сервер для получения списка городов относящихся к Региону, получаем обрабатываем - формируем список - и показываем  select (Город)

Чтоб нельзя было нажать кнопку без заполнения всех полей - то тут следующий алгоритм- при заполнении любого поля вызываем функцию, в которой проходим все поля формы с проверкой на заполненность - если все поля заполнены - показываем кнопку - иначе не показываем. Ну на сервере все равно нада будет повторно проверять - поэтому это всего лишь фишка - декорация, -никакой защиты нет.